# Python: roslaunch KeyboardInterrupt exception not caught try---catch

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using roslaunch to launch several nodes that do some calculations. I want to print some variables continuously into a file. Part of the code looks like this:

```
class Agent:

def __init__(self, var1, ...):

    filename = 'stdout_' + str(ID)
    self.stdout_log = open(filename, 'w')

    ## ROS Topics and Services ################################################
    ###########################################################################
    rospy.init_node('agent', anonymous=True)

    myservice = '/serve'
    srv = rospy.Service(myservice, Service_One, self.handle_serve)

    self.publish_global = rospy.Publisher('msgs', Message_Type, queue_size=200)
    rospy.Subscriber('trigger', Message_Type, self.callback)
    ###########################################################################
if __name__ == '__main__':
agent = Agent(var1,...)

try:
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        print 'stuff'
        agent.stdout_log.write('stuff')
except rospy.ROSInterruptException:
    pass
finally:
    agent.stdout_log.close()
```

If I give ctrl-c from the terminal window where I have exectued roslaunch, the file is created but there's nothing in it. After some trials, I suspect that it is because the file doesn't get to close. I try to ctrl-c the nodes themselves, but it doesn't work. If I remove the ros related declarations in **init** then I can stop the node with ctrl-c.  What can I do?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/237096/python:-roslaunch-keyboardinterrupt-exception-not-caught-try---catch/) by [highWaters](https://answers.ros.org/users/25790/highwaters/) on ROS Answers with karma: 176 on 2016-06-15

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In the condition of the main loop use this:

```
while not ropy.is_shutdown() :
   rospy.sleep(1.0)
```

rospy.is_shutdown is required to attend to the ending signals of the process.

---

Originally posted by [Pablo Iñigo Blasco](https://answers.ros.org/users/356/pablo-i%C3%B1igo-blasco/) with karma: 2982 on 2016-06-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [highWaters](https://answers.ros.org/users/25790/highwaters/) on 2016-06-15**:
Thank you!!!